# Fire event in page from mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a Window that hosts a Page. I want to fire an event on the Page when the user clicks cancel when closing the MainWindow. At the moment I am struggling to work out how to fire the event on the Page from Window. Here is the event on the Page;

```
public void OnChangeUserEvent()
{
    var _employeeSelectionWindow = new EmployeeSelectionWindow();
    _employeeSelectionWindow.ReturnEmployeeDetails += LoadSelectedEmployeeAsLoggedInUser;
    _employeeSelectionWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

And here is when I would like to fire it (this method is in a Window, hosting the page);

```
private void OnWindowClosed(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show(@"Are you sure you want to exit the database?" + Environment.NewLine + "Click cancel to change user.",
                                "", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
    {
        //Fire the event on the page here!
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

I've tried using something like;

```
((LoginPage)e.Content).UserChangeEvent+= new EventHandler(MainWindow_NewRecordSaved);
```

nothing has worked for me so far.

Comment: Can you save the instance of the page as a variable in Window before adding page to NavigationService (If you are adding the page in window in code behind of windows) ? Saving the reference for the same page that is showing will allow you to call the public method the page.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating new instance of LoginPage you can pass reference of main window to it

```
var loginPage = new LoginPage(this); //this indicate reference of main window.
```

inside the LoginPage's constructor you can add event handler as

```
 public LoginPage(MainWindowClass mainWin)
{
   mainWin.UserChangeEvent += LocalEventHanlderMethod;
}
```

When you raise event from onclosing event of main window this should be called.